# Get the list of commits using JGIT remotely

Tags: java, git, jgit, kallithea

Is it possible to iterate through the list of commits remotely without having to clone the repo?

If no, what is/are the recommended approach to do so.

Use case:
 Display the list of commits on a web page and must always be up to date.

Sample output:
[image: expected output]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without cloning: that depends on the remote API proposed by the remote Git repos hosting server.

For example, GItHub has a [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) which can be used to [list commits in a repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository).
And it has a [Java library](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core) (so, no JGit involved here)

Comment: We are using kallithea, and I checked the kallithea API and appears to me that they does not provide such functionality. If you have an idea to do so will be much appreciated. Thank you once again.

Comment: @MarcRejohnCastillano Then you have other libraries to chose from: https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, are those API usable only if the repository exists in GitHub, right? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, my answer uses GitHub as an example of remote repo service. What is your as own current use case?

Comment: @MarcRejohnCastillano Then you need to use its client API: http://kallithea.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/api.html#api-client, but it does not appear to include getting commits of a remote Git repo.

Comment: @MarcRejohnCastillano You would then need to code your own API listener on that kallithea server (if you control and manage it) in order to do that query for you and send you back the expected result.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions. Helped a lot. God bless.

Comment: You can [iterate heads/branches/tags](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ListRemoteRepository.java), with JGit you could download the repository into a temporary directory, do your work and delete it again, although that will take some time for larger repositories.